# Passing multiple POJO to restful api using Jersey Pojo mapping feature and Jquery

Tags: rest, mapping, jersey, pojo

Currently we have the Pojo Mapping feature enabled as below:

```
<servlet-class>
com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
<param-value>com.rest.services</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Rest method is as follows

```
    @POST
        @Path("/test")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response addSomething(POJOObject pObj){
           }
```

Is it possible to pass more than one Pojo object
as below

```
 @POST
            @Path("/test")
            @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            public Response addSomething(POJOObject pObj,POJOObject2 pObj1){
               }
```

This can be achieved by creating an aggregate object containing both the objects (pObj and pObj1)

But was wondering if there is any other solution to achieve this.